# Can you confirm my understanding of this use of "trimmer"?

Tags: joists, beam

[This definition of the term "trimmer" says](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trimmer):

> A trimmer is a beam across an opening, such as a hearth, into which the ends of joists can be fitted.

Could someone confirm if the beam is horizontally positioned while the joists in this case are vertically positioned? I wish there was an image to show. Thank you!

Comment: Quick [search](http://images.bing.com/?q=trimmer+beam) says 'yes,' the trimmer beams and joists are all vertical.

Comment: Wait. I've just written up an answer, but, it occurred to me... When you say "horizontally positioned" vs "vertically positioned", do you mean that the (assumed dimensional lumber) is placed "horizontally" with it's wide dimension horizontal and narrow dimension vertical, vs "vertically" with its narrow dimension horizontal and wide dimension vertical? i.e. a "horizontal" placement of a 2x12 would have an 11" flat surface you could easily walk on, while a "vertical" placement would have a 1.5" vertical surface you'd have to balance on?

Comment: You stopped by to correct a grammatical error, but you didn't clarify what you meant by "horizontal"...

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response! What I am trying to ask is if the beam and the joists are perpendicular to each other. Thank you so very much for your assistance and help!

Comment: if you are talking about a trimmer beam, then say "trimmer beam", not just "trimmer"

Comment: Wow... "Horizontal" and "vertical" are _not_ good synonyms for perpendicular and parallel. You'll really confuse a lot of people if you try to use them that way. "Horizontal" is usual used to reference something that is (basically) in line with the horizon, while "vertical" means going from the ground toward the sky. Parallel & perpendicular have no default, gravity related connotation inherent with them.

Comment: Thank you so very much for correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are incorrect.

On that same page, but slightly lower in a box with a grey background, it reads:

[image]

> Also called: **trimmer joist** a beam in a floor or roof structure attached to truncated joists in order to leave an opening for a staircase, chimney, etc
> <sup>--Image *and* quote [source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trimmer), the same as in the OP</sup>

Joists are, by definition, horizontal. Studs and posts are vertical.

Here is a very quick top-down view of a very small floor system with the *trimmer joist* in brown, while all the "regular" joists are in black:

[image]

The trimmer joist (often doubled, to support the load) frames an opening in the floor for the edge of a hearth, a stairway, plumbing from above, whatever.

Comment: I've owned homes with these installed around block chimneys, but even as a long-time builder I wouldn't have associated the term. In modern parlance it might be a "girder joist" or "girder beam". You'd see the same across the head of a stairwell, for example.

Comment: I just had to do this to a joist where the shower drain, of course, landed right in the middle of the joist. I just called it "heading it off", but what do I know...

Comment: Hello, once again thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations - I really appreciate it!